# rospy logging configuration file

Tags: ros, rosout, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The logging overview page for rospy (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging) mentions that as of Diamondback, logging is configured using a file in the fileConfig format.

Is there an example of how to set this up?

Also, do there exist handlers that publish to rosout, and can those be configured from the file as well?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10299/rospy-logging-configuration-file/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html

You cannot configure rosout via the rospy logging format.

In the future, I hope to use a non-logging-module-based solution for rospy, as it is difficult to manipulate.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0